# What is the full sentence of 'X to the rescue'?

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms, ellipsis, minor-sentences

Almost all well-formed English sentences have a verb. Most grammar books for ELLs suggest that we can understand imperative sentences as having the implied "You" as the subject. For example,

> *Sit down.* (= You sit down.)

I noticed that in a movie I watched, it has this sentence, *Judah Buckner to the rescue*, which can be generalized to the construction: ***X to the rescue***.

Though the meaning is clear, I would like to know how to analyze this construction as a sentence.  Should I regard it as a fragment? Or should I understand it as an ellipsis, as shown below?

> *Superman to the rescue.*
>     (= Here is Superman to the rescue.?)
>     (= Here comes Superman to the rescue.?)

Comment: I think of it as, "Here comes..."

Comment: An imperative sentence with an implied *you* subject is still a sentence. **X to the rescue** isn't; it's a fragment (technically, an ejaculation) with an idiosyncratic form. Any suitable addition can turn it into a complete sentence, such as "It's..."

Comment: @chrylis I think OP understands that it's not a formally complete sentence, in the TenthGradeEnglish sense, but it **is** a complete utterance; he is asking how it would best be expressed as a formal sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the comment, I'd read it as:

> Judah Buckner **is coming** to the rescue!

This would probably be said by Judah Buckner himself, speaking in third person.

Comment: +1 I sorta like OP's "Here comes", but you've put your finger on the classic context: it's a self-proclamation,  ►\*\*!!Olaf Trygvasson, Gentleman Adventurer!!\*\*◄